# Como asignar valores de una columna a otra con grupos y condiciones en python

Tags: python, condiciones, while

he probado con el escenario 2 pero no me ha servido. Voy a explicar el problema completo porque he intentado simplificarlo y esto solo ha servido para causar confusión (lo siento). Lo que tengo es un problema para optimizar la asignación de carteras de clientes a unos comerciales. Las columnas serían center (área comercial), client (nº cliente), user (el comercial responsable de ese cliente, **en caso de no estar relleno significa que el cliente es nuevo**), value (es un indicador del valor de ese cliente) y assigned_user, que es una columna creada por mi, para asignar el comercial adecuado a cada cliente. Partiríamos de un df similar a este (es un fragmento del original):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
"center": ['0060','0060','0060','0060','0060','0060','0060','0060','0060','0060','0070','0070','0070','0070','0070','0070','0070','0070','0080','0080','0080','0080','0080','0080','0080','0080','0080','0080','0080','0080','0080'],
"client": ['C00001','C00002','C00003','C00004','C00005','C00006','C00007','C00008','C00009','C00010','C00011','C00012','C00013','C00014','C00015','C00016','C00017','C00018','C00019','C00020','C00021','C00022','C00023','C00024','C00025','C00026','C00027','C00028','C00029','C00030','C00031'],
"user": ['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','NaN','NaN','C','C','C','C','C','D','D','D','E','E','E','E','E','F','F','F','G','G','NaN','NaN','NaN'],
"value": [5,5,3,5,2,5,2,2,2,3,5,4,4,1,1,3,3,3,5,3,2,2,5,5,2,2,5,3,1,2,3], 
"assigned_user": ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN']
})
```

Lo que necesito con este dataset es hacer un reparto lo más equitativo posible en cuanto a valor de clientes para cada comercial(user) y según el centro. Es decir, para el centro 0060, tengo 2 comerciales (A y B) y un valor total de clientes de 34. Entonces, lo que necesito, es hacer un reparto en la columna assigned_user lo más equitativo posible.

Si para el centro 0060 tengo 2 comerciales y el valor total de todos los clientes es de 34, cada uno deberá tener una cartera de un valor igual o lo más cercano posible a 17, y con la condición, de que para cada comercial (user), he de intentar mantener el máximo posible de clientes que ya tenga, es decir si en este caso, el comercial A, tiene ya una cartera con un valor de 20, le tendré que quitar un cliente con valor 3 y asignárselo a B. De esa misma manera, los clientes que no tienen un NaN en la columna user, deberán ir asignados también al comercial B, de forma que tanto A como B acabarán teniendo una cartera con valor a 17 cada uno, y A mantendrá 4 de sus 5 clientes iniciales, y B tendrá sus mismos clientes iniciales, más otros que se le asignan después hasta llegar a un valor de 17.

En el caso del centro 0080, que tiene 3 comerciales (E, F y G) y un valor total de clientes de 40, cada comercial deberá tener una cartera con un valor cercano a 13,3. En el caso de E, tiene asignado una cartera inicial con valor = 17, y para F y G son 9 y 8 respectivamente, además, hay 3 clientes en ese centro con un valor total de 6 que no están asignados a nadie. A la hora de rellenar la columna "assigned_user", al comercial E, habría que quitarle clientes hasta que su cartera estuviese lo más cercana posible a 13,3, y lo que le quitemos a E, además de los que no están asignados a nadie en la columna "user", habría que asignárselos a F y G, hasta que cada uno tenga una cartera lo más aproximada posible a 13,3.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Supongo que el `dataset` es más grande y por eso no lo haces manualmente pero ignorando eso, ¿Qué sucede si las filas contiguas no suman 10? Por ejemplo que hubiera 5, 3, 3 ¿Qué habría que hacer?

Comment: Otra pregunta, en tu ejemplo en la columna `usuario` aparece un usuario diferente casualmente donde debería iniciar el conteo `value`, ¿Esto aplica para todo el `dataset`? Si es así, tal vez hay una forma más sencilla de hacerlo

Comment: Hola. Si, el dataset es más grande, este era de ejemplo. Si las filas contiguas no suman 10 no pasa nada, en el momento que se supera 10 (ya sea 11, 12 o 15) se para ahí. Por ejemplo si hay tres filas y son 5, 3 y 5, serían 13 y dejaría de asignar a B y pasaría a asignar a C hasta que C sume también 10 (o un número un poco mayor). Como comentas más abajo, esto aplica a todo el data set (es mucho mayor con más centros, y usuarios), solo he puesto este fragmento como ejemplo y si se resuelve, luego poder ampliarlo al resto. Gracias!!

Comment: Ok, ¿Siempre va a aparecer en la columna `usuario` algún usuario justo en la fila donde se debe crear el grupo? Por ejemplo en la fila que apareció `C` o ¿Qué sucede si un grupo supera 10 y hay que "cerrarlo" pero el grupo siguiente no tiene ningún usuario?

Comment: Disculpa, no entiendo bien la pregunta. Lo que necesito es ir cerrando grupos con valor 10 (o muy cercano). Para el centro 0060 y tengo 3 usuarios (A, B y C), lo que necesito es que cada uno de ellos tenga un valor similar asignado. En el caso de A, ya tiene el valor 10, en el caso B y C tienen un valor asignado de 5 cada uno (columna assigned_user). Lo que necesitaría es algo que me permita ir asignando los NaN de la columna assigned_user a B o C (me daría igual el orden), hasta que cada uno tenga un valor lo más cercano posible a 10, y sin que quede ningún NaN en la columna assigned.

Comment: En realidad me daría igual si A tiene un valor de 10, B de 9 y C de 11, lo que necesito es que quede lo más igualitario posible.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda @HeyTalePazguato, he probado con la solución 2 (la uno no me sirve) y no me ha servido, he editado el enunciado del problema porque he intentado simplificarlo para hacerlo más sencillo y solo he conseguido hacerlos más difícil de entender. Espero que con la nueva explicación quede más claro.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Yo creo que es difícil encontrar una solución para todas las posibles combinaciones ya que si el orden de las filas para los grupos no importa se podría asignar valores a usuarios para intentar siempre obtener 10

Otro escenario que mencioné en los comentarios y no está claro es, si tuvieras un `dataframe` donde varias filas seguidas no tuvieran ningún usuario asignado, por ejemplo:

```
    Center  user    value   asigned_user
0   60      A       5       A
1   60      A       5       A
2   60      B       2       B
3   60      B       3       B
4   60      NaN     2       NaN
5   60      NaN     3       NaN
6   60      C       5       NaN
7   60      NaN     5       NaN
8   60      D       6       NaN
9   60      NaN     6       NaN
10  60      NaN     2       NaN
11  60      NaN     2       NaN
12  60      NaN     2       NaN
13  60      NaN     5       NaN
```

Como se puede ver, las filas 9-13 no tienen ningún usuario asignado, ¿Qué se haría en esos casos? ¿Se inventaría un usuario o se dejan en blanco? O lo que preguntaba es, en tu ejemplo aparece el usuario `C` justo en la fila donde se debería crear un nuevo "grupo", ¿Esto siempre se cumple? En dado caso el `dataset` anterior estaría mal y debería ser así:

```
    Center  user    value   asigned_user
0   60      A       5       A
1   60      A       5       A
2   60      B       2       B
3   60      B       3       B
4   60      NaN     2       NaN
5   60      NaN     3       NaN
6   60      C       5       NaN
7   60      NaN     5       NaN
8   60      D       6       NaN
9   60      NaN     6       NaN
10  60      E       2       NaN
11  60      NaN     2       NaN
12  60      NaN     2       NaN
13  60      NaN     5       NaN
```

Donde aparece un nuevo usuario `E` justo en la fila donde hay que crear un nuevo grupo.

Con lo anterior como contexto, sin conocer todas las reglas de creación de tus datos no hay una fórmula para cubrir todos los casos por lo que propongo dos soluciones que podrían serte útiles pero tendrás que adaptar a tus necesidades.

**Nota:** Agregué algunas filas al `dataset` para que se vea un poco mejor como funcionan los diferentes métodos.

### Escenario 1

Si siempre aparece un nuevo usuario justo en la fila donde hay que crear un nuevo grupo entonces la solución es muy fácil, bastaría con utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) en combinación con [`pandas.DataFrame.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) de la siguiente forma:

```
df['asigned_user'] = df['asigned_user'].fillna(df['user']).ffill()
```

**Nota:** En este método no haría falta ni hacer la suma de `value` ya que siempre habrá algún usuario en la fila justo donde debería asignarse un nuevo grupo.

Explicación, utilizamos `fillna` para rellenar los `NaN` y utilizamos los valores de la columna `user` para hacerlo, únicamente al ejecutar `df['asigned_user'] = df['asigned_user'].fillna(df['user'])` obtendríamos el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
    Center  user    value   asigned_user
0   60      A       5       A
1   60      A       5       A
2   60      B       2       B
3   60      B       3       B
4   60      NaN     2       NaN
5   60      NaN     3       NaN
6   60      C       5       C
7   60      NaN     5       NaN
8   60      D       6       D
9   60      NaN     6       NaN
10  60      E       2       E
11  60      NaN     2       NaN
12  60      NaN     2       NaN
13  60      NaN     5       NaN
```

Es decir, se copian los valores de la columna `usuario` y sean `NaN` en `asigned_user`.

Luego con `ffill` rellenamos los valores `NaN` hacia adelante (Te recomiendo leer la documentación para entender los métodos de llenado).

El `dataframe` resultante sería:

```
    Center  user    value   asigned_user
0   60      A       5       A
1   60      A       5       A
2   60      B       2       B
3   60      B       3       B
4   60      NaN     2       B
5   60      NaN     3       B
6   60      C       5       C
7   60      NaN     5       C
8   60      D       6       D
9   60      NaN     6       D
10  60      E       2       E
11  60      NaN     2       E
12  60      NaN     2       E
13  60      NaN     5       E
```

Ejemplo completo utilizando tus datos desde un archivo "sample2.csv":

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv')
df['asigned_user'] = df['asigned_user'].fillna(df['user']).ffill()
print(df)
```

### Escenario 2

No se sabe si los usuarios de la columna `user` van a estar justo en la fila donde se deba crear un nuevo grupo, en este caso la suma de `value` es importante pero el problema es que al no existir usuarios en la columna `user` tal vez habría grupos donde ho sea posible asignar ningún usuario.

Para lograr dividir los grupos vamos a crear un arreglo con los divisores de los grupos, es decir, si se desean hacer grupos cada que la suma en `value` sea 10 entonces los "divisores" serían `[10, 20, 30, etc...]`.

Primero obtenemos el número de usuarios únicos en la columna `user` esto nos dirá cuántos grupos vamos a tener y creamos el arreglo con los números que servirán para segmentar los grupos

```
shift_num = 10*np.arange(1,len(df['user'].unique()))
print(shift_num)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
```

Luego vamos a obtener los índices de las filas donde se tendría que crear un nuevo grupo con [`numpy.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)

```
idx = np.searchsorted(df['value'].values.cumsum(), shift_num,'right')
print(idx)
```

Esto devuelve el siguiente arreglo:

```
array([ 2,  6,  8,  9, 13], dtype=int64)
```

**Nota:** Como se puede ver, la fórmula intenta crear un grupo en 8 y un nuevo grupo en 9, esto es porque se intenta que ningún grupo tenga más de 10 (Por lo que tendrías que adaptar la fórmula).

Al no saber si siempre vamos a tener el número correcto de usuarios, es decir, si tenemos 6 usuarios únicos se esperaría que la suma total de `value` sea `60` o un valor muy cercano.

Yo lo que haría sería obtener la suma de `value` y dividirla entre el número de usuarios únicos en `user` y así obtener un tamaño de grupo con el que se intentaría hacer que todos los grupos fueran más o menos del mismo tamaño, algo así (Esto no es parte de la respuesta, solo una forma en como yo obtendría los grupos).

```
group_size = df['value'].sum()/len(df['user'].unique())
print(group_size)
shift_num = group_size*np.arange(1,len(df['user'].unique()))
shift_num
```

Para finalizar utilizamos [`pandas.DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) para  buscar los índices que coincidan con el arreglo `idx` que contiene los índices donde debería crearse un nuevo grupo.

```
df['asigned_user'].where(df.index.isin(idx)).fillna(df['user']).ffill()
```

Para corregir un poco el posible al comportamiento de la fórmula (Ya que podría crear un nuevo grupo como en las filas 8 y 9 tal como se comentó anteriormente) utilicé `fillna()` para copiar el valor de `user` en caso de haberlo

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv')
shift_num = 10*np.arange(1,len(df['user'].unique()))
idx = np.searchsorted(df['value'].values.cumsum(), shift_num,'right')
df['asigned_user'] = df['asigned_user'].where(df.index.isin(idx)).fillna(df['user']).ffill()
print(df)
```

Esto devuelve el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
    Center  user    value   asigned_user
0   60      A       5       A
1   60      A       5       A
2   60      B       2       B
3   60      B       3       B
4   60      NaN     2       B
5   60      NaN     3       B
6   60      C       5       C
7   60      NaN     5       C
8   60      D       6       D
9   60      NaN     6       D
10  60      E       2       E
11  60      NaN     2       E
12  60      NaN     2       E
13  60      NaN     5       E
```

### Conclusión

Como se comentó al inicio, creo que hay escenarios que no se han considerado ya que no conocemos las reglas o lineamientos que se utilizan para crear el `dataset` original por lo que lo más probable es que tengas que adaptar alguno de estos métodos para lograr tu objetivo final, por lo pronto con los datos que pusiste como ejemplo y los que yo inventé funciona correctamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, he probado con la solución 2 (la uno no me sirve) y no me ha servido, he editado el enunciado del problema porque he intentado simplificarlo para hacerlo más sencillo y solo he conseguido hacerlos más difícil de entender. Espero que con la nueva explicación quede más claro.